# Динамическе и статические n-мерные массивы в С++

Tags: c++, массивы, winapi

Похоже я не совсем понимаю что из себя представляют двумерные (n-мерные) массивы в C++, чем они являются для оперативной памяти и чем двумерный массив объявленный на стеке вот таким образом:

```
RGBQUAD frameBuffer[300][300];
```

отличается от динамически объявленного двумерного массива:

```
RGBQUAD ** frame = new RGBQUAD*[height];

for (uint32_t i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
    frame[i] = new RGBQUAD[width];
    std::fill_n(frame[i], width, clearColor);
}
```

**Теперь немного о самой задаче**

Решил я попробовать написать что-то вроде software-renderera, начать решил с самого базового - точки (а именно вывода ее на экран). В WinAPI конечно же есть средства для рисования и установки цвета отдельных пикселей, но после небольшого ковыряния данной темы, я понял что правильным подходом будет именно подготовка кадра как bitmap картинки, а затем показ данной картинки на окне. То есть по задумке у меня будет формироваться bitmap, который я буду с определенной частотой показывать на окне, таким образом получив что-то вроде анимации. Сам по себе показ картинки у меня осуществляется примерно вот так:

```
// Cоздать временный bitmap (4 байта на пиксель), последний параметр типа void*
// Это может быть как одномерный так и двумерный массив структур RGBQUAD
HBITMAP hBitMap = CreateBitmap(width, height, 1, 8 * 4, pixels);

// Получить device context окна
HDC hdc = GetDC(hWnd);

// Временный DC для переноса bit-map'а
HDC srcHdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);

// Связать bit-map с временным DC
SelectObject(srcHdc, hBitMap);

// Копировать содержимое временного DC в DC окна
BitBlt(
    hdc,    // HDC назначения
    0,      // Начало вставки по оси X
    0,      // Начало вставки по оси Y
    width,  // Ширина
    height, // Высота
    srcHdc, // Исходный HDC (из которого будут копироваться данные)
    0,      // Начало считывания по оси X
    0,      // Начало считывания по оси Y
    SRCCOPY // Копировать
);

// Уничтожить bit-map
DeleteObject(hBitMap);
// Уничтожить временный DC
DeleteDC(srcHdc);
// Уничтожить DC
DeleteDC(hdc);
```

Все нормально работало, причем удивительно что работало как с одномерным, так и двумерным массивом структур, в качестве параметра `pixels` (в функции `CreateBitmap`). Будто бы двумерные массивы в С++, которые объявлены не динамически, воспринимаются как одномерные.. И тут я попробовал выделить этот самый фрейм-буфер (двумерный массив) динамически, в куче, то есть по сути создать массив указателей на массивы (выше пример, как именно я это делал). И в итоге все перестало работать, теперь функция `CreateBitmap` этого не понимает. Я попытался тогда динамически выделить одномерный массив, как-то вот так:

```
RGBQUAD * frame = new RGBQUAD[width * height];
std::fill_n(frame, width * height, clearColor);
```

И все тут же стало работать.

**Вопрос:** в чем дело? Что я упускаю? Действительно ли в С++ двумерные массивы объявленные динамически это совсем не то же самое что двумерные массивы объявленные обычным способом? В чем разница? За ранее спасибо.

Comment: Да, разница есть.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Для обычных массивов, вроде `int a[3]` и `int b[3][3]`, в памяти хранятся только сами элементы подряд, и все.

```
int a[5]

.------.------.------.------.------.
| a[0] | a[1] | a[2] | a[3] | a[4] |
'------'------'------'------'------'

int b[3][2]

.---------.---------.---------.---------.---------.---------.
| b[0][0] | b[0][1] | b[1][0] | b[1][1] | b[2][0] | b[2][1] | 
'---------'---------'---------'---------'---------'---------'
```

А вот так выглядит одномерный массив, созданный через `new`. Указатель на первый элемент хранится отдельно.

```
int *c = new int[5]

.-----.
|  c  |
'--.--'
   |
   |
   V
.-----.-----.-----.-----.-----.
| [0] | [1] | [2] | [3] | [4] |
'-----'-----'-----'-----'-----'
```

Для многомерного массива вы использовали массив указателей на массивы, он же ["рваный" массив](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array).

```
int **d = new int*[3];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    d[i] = new int[4];

.-----.
|  d  |
'--.--'
   |
   |
   V
.-----.-----.-----.
| [0] | [1] | [2] |
'--.--'--.--'--.--'
   |     |     |        .--------.--------.--------.--------.
   |     |     '------> | [2][0] | [2][1] | [2][2] | [2][3] |
   |     |              '--------'--------'--------'--------'
   |     |        .--------.--------.--------.--------.
   |     '------> | [1][0] | [1][1] | [1][2] | [1][3] |
   |              '--------'--------'--------'--------'
   |        .--------.--------.--------.--------.
   '------> | [0][0] | [0][1] | [0][2] | [0][3] |
            '--------'--------'--------'--------'
```

В таком случае строчки не обязательно расположены в памяти подряд, в отличие от массива, созданного обычным способом, вроде `int f[3][4]`.

Самый удобный (мне кажется) способ сделать так, чтобы строчки шли в памяти подряд, вы уже нашли: Использовать одномерный массив: `int *g = new int[w * h];`.

Если хотите использовать удобный синтаксис для доступа к элементам: `g[y][x]` вместо `g[y * w + x]`, то лучше всего сделать свой класс двухмерного массива с перегруженным оператором `[]`.

---

Кстати, очень советую вместо `new` и `delete` использовать `std::vector`.

С new/delete легко забыть освободить память, и получить утечку. Замучаетесь искать потом.

Особенно легко забыть, если у вас в коде что-то выбросит исключение.

А `std::vector` следит за освобождением памяти за вас.

Comment: Если я сделаю класс с перегруженным оператором, либо, например, функцию установки значения элемента с координатами (x,y), то мне ведь всякий раз при такой установке нужно будет делать вычисления (y * w + x). Насколько это оптимально, если подобных установок значений придется делать много и часто (рисовать линии из таких точек, затем растеризовывать треугольники и т.д) ? Это на производительности не должно сказаться критически?

Comment: @AlexNem: Это будет работать быстрее чем вектор стандарта. В особенности если ваш класс не будет иметь методов вроде `push_back`, т.е. инициализировали одной длиной и такую длину используем.

Comment: @AlexNem Мне кажется, не настолько медленно, чтобы об этом беспокоиться. Но если интересно, померяйте время и сравните, что лучше. Если вдруг почему-то окажется, что двойной указатель быстрее, то можно создать массив указателей, указывающий на разные куски одномерного массива: `int *storage = new int[w*h]; int **array = new int*[w]; for (int i = 0; i < w; i++) array[i] = storage + w * i;` В этом случае, у вас и данные подряд находятся, и доступ идет через двойной указатель (`array[i][j]`).

Answer (score 4):

Разница в том что статический двумерный массив ничем не отличается от одномерного, 
Значит расположен он будет так (пример двумерного статического массива 5x5) на схеме `ロ` обозначает ячейку

```
ロロロロロ ロロロロロ ロロロロロ
```

А в динамическом двумерном массиве все первые элементы это указатели, и расположены все элементы в рознь по оперативной памяти  (пример двумерного динамического массива 5x5) на схеме `&` обозначает ссылку

```
&1 ---> ロロロロロ
&2 ---> ロロロロロ
&3 ---> ロロロロロ
&4 ---> ロロロロロ
&5 ---> ロロロロロ
```

Соответственно они разбросаны по оперативной памяти хаотично в отличии от статического двумерного массива

Если вам нужен непрерывный двумерный массив, есть вариант

```
int arr = new int[w*h];
```

Comment: Но смогу ли я потом обращаться к данному массиву как к двумерному ? (то есть arr[y][x] =10) Это ведь по сути одномерный массив? Или можно как-то схитрить и преобразовать указатели? Если да, то как это правильно делается?

Comment: Да, правильно создать специальный класс с перегруженным оператором `[][]`