# Передать статический двумерный с массив в функцию

Tags: c++, массивы, функции, указатели

я пытаюсь передать двумерный массив в функцию. И у меня появляется следующая ошибка:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Я думала, что указатель на указатель и имя массива массивов это одно и тоже, но видимо это не так... Массив это отдельный тип данных? Я запуталась. Возможно, вопрос тупой, но я буду очень благодарна, если кто-нибудь мне объяснит, как это работает. ***Что за тип 'int (*)[2]' ?***

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


void funk(int **arr){
    cout << arr[0][0] << " " << arr[0][1] << endl << arr[1][0] << " " << arr[1][1] << endl;
}


int main(){
    int arr[2][2] = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
    funk(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Уже был такой вопрос [Передать двумерный статический массив в функцию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/464373/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E)

Comment: Там о том, как передать массив, а я не понимаю в чём разница между двумерным статическим массивом (его именем) и указателем на указатель.

Comment: `Что за тип 'int (*)[2]' ?` — это указатель на массив из двух элементов типа `int`. Функция `funk` ожидает получить указатель на элемент массива указателей `int*`, но вы передаёте в неё указатель на элемент массива массивов `int[2]`. Возможно запись `funk(arr);` будет проще понять в таком виде: `funk(&arr[0]);`. Также посмотрите [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/848962).

Comment: Правильно, массив - это отдельный, независимый тип данных, в нем содержатся только элементы массива, без всяких указателей. В подходящем контексте имя массива может неявно преобразовываться в указатель на первый элемент. Например имя `arr` может быть неявно преобразовано в указатель на первый элемент - `int ( * )[2]` Эта запись читается согласно спиральному правилу, начиная с середины. А вообще делайте алиас типа и передавайте по ссылке `using my_array = int [2][2]; void funk(my_array & arr)`

Comment: А динамический массив это тоже отдельный тип данных? Если его использовать, то он вроде бы ведёт себя как указатель на указатель. Где вообще можно подробнее про реализацию всего этого дела почитать?

Comment: И в "int (*)[2]" зачем указываются скобочки? Они что-то значат? Почему не "int*[2]" ?

Comment: `int* [2]` — этот тип обозначает массив из двух элементов типа `int*`. Т.е. если написать `int* arr[2]`, то `arr` — это массив из двух элементов, где каждый элемент — это указатель `int*`.