# На какие операции и типы распадается имя динамического двухмерного массива?

Tags: c++, динамические-массивы

Для примера, определим, чему эквивалентно выражение y[2][3] в нотации указателей и на какие шаги и типы оно распадается:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    int **y = new int *[5];

    for (int i = 0; i != 5; ++i) {
        y[i] = new int[7];
    }

    y[2][3] == *(*(y + 2) + 3);

    // Шаг 1
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(y), int **>);
    // y — это указатель на массив указателей на массивы
    // распада массива здесь не происходит, потому что
    // y - это не массив, а указатель на указатель
    // y - содержит адрес первого указателя: *y == y[0]

    int **ptr_row_2 = y + 2; // получаем адрес указателя 2 (который содержит адрес строки 2)
    // ptr_row_2 == &y[2]

    // Шаг 2
    int *&get_row_2 = *(y + 2); // первое обращение к памяти
    // извлекаем указатель на первый элемент строки 2
    // get_row_2 == y[2]

    // Шаг 3
    int *ptr_item_3 = *(y + 2) + 3; // получаем адрес на элемент 3 строки 2
    // ptr_item_3 == &y[2][3]

    // Шаг 4
    int &get_item_3 = *(*(y + 2) + 3); // второе обращение к памяти
    // извлекаем элемент 3 строки 2
    // get_item_3 == y[2][3]

    for (int i = 0; i != 5; ++i) {
        delete[] y[i];
    }

    delete[] y;

    return 0;
}
```

Вопрос: действительно ли первое обращение к памяти происходит на шаге 2? Или все таки на шаге 3?

Comment: `Обращение к памяти` = `разыменовывание`. Шаги 2 и 3 содержат разыменовывание. Но зачем оно присутствует в шаге 3, если можно написать `int *ptr_item_3 = get_row_2 + 3;`? Когда компилятор интерпретирует последовательные операторы `[][]`, относящиеся к указателям, то всё происходит именно так, как вы написали, но каждый шаг использует результат выполнения предыдущих шагов, а не вычисляет все параметры заново. Поэтому произойдёт два разыменовывания: сначала по первому индексу, потом по второму.

Comment: @maestro, спасибо за ответ. Но всегда ли Обращение к памяти = разыменовывание? Ведь, например, в процессе интерпретации последовательных операторов [][], относящиеся к статическому массиву, происходит несколько операций разыменования, однако ассемблерный код, который генерируется из выражения, например, **x + 2 или x[0][2] (относящихся к статическому массиву), показывает, что операция извлечения данных из памяти выполняется там только один раз.

Comment: @maestro, я понимаю, что у статического массива физическое размещение в памяти - одним последовательным блоком, и адрес элемента вычисляется за один раз (в отличие от динамического), несмотря на многомерность массива. Но в выражениях типа *(*(x + 2) + 3) (для статического массива int[5][7]), два раза происходит распад имени массива на указатель, один раз на x[*][7], а второй раз на int *, и меняются типы промежуточных выражений, на которые распадается x[2][3]. Разве в процессе этого не происходит несколько операций разыменований?

Comment: Написанное выше справедливо только тогда, когда последовательные операторы `[][]` относятся к указателям. Статические массивы обрабатываются иначе. Посмотрите этот ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/848962/3380

Comment: Выражение `(*(x + 2) + 3)` для статического массива `int x[5][7]` не компилируется.

Comment: @maestro, Что Вы имеете ввиду под "не компилируется"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот этот код

```
int a[5][7];
size_t i = 3;
size_t j = 2;
int main()
{
    a[i][j] = 4;
    return 0;
}
```

на x86-64 GCC скомпилируется в

```
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     rdx, QWORD PTR i[rip]
        mov     rcx, QWORD PTR j[rip]
        mov     rax, rdx
        sal     rax, 3
        sub     rax, rdx
        add     rax, rcx
        mov     DWORD PTR a[0+rax*4], 4
        mov     eax, 0
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

Здесь видно, что смещение адреса для записи в массив вычисляется по формуле: `(7i+j)*4`, где 7 - второй размер массива, 4 - размер `int`. (если прописать расчёт полностью, то получится так: `((i<<3) - i + j) * 4`). В результате происходит одно обращение к памяти по адресу, который вычислен на основе размера массива и переданных индексах.

Если же использовать разыменовывания:

```
int a[5][7];
size_t i = 3;
size_t j = 2;
int main()
{
    *(*(a+i)+j) = 5;
    return 0;
}
```

то оно скомпилируется так:

```
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     rdx, QWORD PTR i[rip]
        mov     rax, rdx
        sal     rax, 3
        sub     rax, rdx
        mov     rcx, rax
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR j[rip]
        add     rax, rcx
        sal     rax, 2
        add     rax, OFFSET FLAT:a
        mov     DWORD PTR [rax], 5
        mov     eax, 0
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

Здесь формула расчёта смещения выглядит так: `((i << 3) - i + j) << 2`, что эквивалентно выражению `(7i+j)*4`. Получаем, что выражения

```
a[i][j] = 4;
```

и

```
*(*(a+i)+j) = 5;
```

для статического массива `a` порождают одинаковый код, содержащий вычисление смещения относительно начала массива и одно обращение к памяти. Следовательно, ранее заявленное мной высказывание, что `обращение к памяти` = `разыменовывание` неверно.

Comment: maestro, спасибо большое за такой обстоятельный ответ. Если вас не затруднит, объясните пожалуйста что значит операция (i<<3)? Точнее, почему (i<<3) - i == 7 * i ?? Каким образом выражение в левой части не содержит индекс 7 и при этом истинно? Прошу прощения за, возможно, глупый вопрос.

Comment: @Давид, Это битовая операция - сдвиг влево. При сдвиге все биты сдвигаются в указанном направлении, а новые становятся равными нулю. Например, число 7 в двоичном виде представляется как `111`. Если применить операцию сдвига влево на 3 элемента, получим `7 << 3 = 111000_2 = 56`. Операция сдвига влево на `n` эквивалентна умножению на `2^n`. Поэтому  `i<<3 - i = 8*i - i = 7*i`. Считается, что в некоторых случаях сдвиги могут работать быстрее, чем умножение, поэтому компиляторы иногда заменяют умножение сдвигами, если это возможно и оправданно.